# ¿Qué formas existen para ordenar archivos?

Tags: python, bucle-for, while, condiciones

Mi pregunta es la siguiente, yo debo ordenar un  archivo de forma que las fechas o los años queden de la siguiente manera(el archivo posee mas de 100.000 registros)

```
Año=1999     
Sala1=123
Sala2=341
Sala3=541
```

(y seria lo mismo con el 2000)

El formato que da el archivo es el siguiente:

Superman-2006-4

Donde el ultimo numero es la sala(4) y despues tenemos el año(2006), como deberia hacer para buscar en el archivo todos los que tengan la misma fecha,(previamente yo saque fecha y sala de todos) y despues sumarlos para que me queden bien?

Parte del codigo para sacar fecha y sala:

```
archivo=open("Peliculas.txt","rt")
leer=archivo.readline()
mayor=0
menor=1996#esto es ya con el año sacado
cont=0
cont2=0
Sala1,Sala2,Sala3,Sala4,Sala5=0,0,0,0,0
while leer:# ACA BUSCO EL MENOR AÑO Y EL MAYOR AÑO PARA PODER ASI ORDENAR EL ARCHIVO
    cont+=1
    controlar=leer[::-1]
    poner_print=controlar[:7]#por aca hay algun error que me caga en la ultima linea, revisarlo
    poner_print=poner_print[::-1]#error solucionado con el cont que para en la linea 49 porque en la 50 surge un error
    Año1=poner_print[:4]
    Sala1=poner_print[5:] 
    if int(Año1)>mayor:
        mayor=int(Año1)#saque el año aca
    if int(Año1)<menor and cont!=49:
        menor=int(Año1)#saque el menor año
    leer=archivo.readline()
print("El año mas grande fue" ,mayor)
print("El año mas chico fue" ,menor)
```

En este caso el ejemplo que hice para que sea algo rapido fue de 50 lineas (el archivo)

Comment: Veo que has aceptado mi respuesta, por lo que deduzco que adiviné correctamente lo que querías hacer. En ese caso te sugiero que edites la pregunta para explicarlo mejor y sobre todo que le cambies el título, ya que lo que que en realidad necesitas no tiene nada qué ver con ordenar archivos, sino con procesar sus contenidos y emitir informes ordenados.

Comment: Muchas gracias por el comentario y por los tips para que quede mejor! Gracias por la ayuda!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ver si lo entendí correctamente. Tú tienes un archivo llamado `"Peliculas.txt"` que contiene por ejemplo líneas como estas:

```
StarWars-2013-5
Tiburon-2005-5
StarWars-2005-2
Tiburon-2003-3
Tiburon-2010-1
Superman-2014-4
StarWars-2009-2
Tiburon-2004-2
StarWars-2016-4
Tiburon-2009-5
```

Es decir, cada línea contiene separado por guiones un título de película, un año y un número que entiendo que es una sala.

Lo que quieres es procesar ese archivo para contar en cada año cuántas veces aparece cada  una de las salas, y después generar un informe ordenado por años y dentro de cada año ordenado por salas ¿correcto?

Si acerté, lo siguiente haría lo que buscas. He hecho uso de un diccionario para meter en él cada año que vaya encontrando. Para cada uno de esos años, creo otro diccionario dentro del anterior, en el que las claves son las salas, y los valores son cuántas veces he visto aparecer esa sala en ese año.

```
resumen= {}

with open("Peliculas.txt") as f:
  for dato in f:
    peli, año, sala = dato.strip().split("-")
    if año not in resumen:
      resumen[año] = {}
    if sala not in resumen[año]:
      resumen[año][sala] = 0
    resumen[año][sala] += 1
```

Como ves, itero por las líneas del fichero (no necesito hacer `readline()`, el bucle  `for dato in f:` me devuelve una línea cada vez), elimino el retorno de carro con `dato.strip()` y divido por el guión con `.split("-")`, para separar en los tres campos. Después añado el año si no estaba ya en el diccionario, y la sala. Finalmente incremento el valor de la sala ese año.

Al terminar el bucle, el diccionario `resumen` tiene lo que buscas, si bien no tiene ningún orden en particular, pues en python los diccionarios no mantienen orden. Por ejemplo, podría tener algo como:

```
{'2013': {'5': 77, '3': 90, '4': 87, '2': 79, '6': 89, '1': 88},
 '2005': {'5': 64, '2': 83, '4': 88, '3': 74, '1': 82, '6': 79},
 etc...
}
```

Para que salga ordenado y en el formato que buscas, el siguiente bucle recorre el diccionario usando `sorted()` sobre sus claves, y va imprimiento sus valores:

```
for año in sorted(resumen):
  print("Año={}".format(año))
  for sala in sorted(resumen[año]):
    print("Sala{}={}".format(sala, resumen[año][sala]))
  print()  # Linea en blanco para separar años
```

Ejemplo de salida:

```
Año=1999
Sala1=77
Sala2=81
Sala3=76
Sala4=85
Sala5=94
Sala6=79

Año=2000
Sala1=91
Sala2=85
Sala3=71
Sala4=80
Sala5=74
Sala6=94

... etc ...
```

### Nota

Puesto que no tenía tus datos, para hacer pruebas generé un fichero de datos aleatorios mediante el siguiente código:

```
import random
pelis = ["Superman", "Tiburon", "StarWars"]
años = list(range(1999, 2019))
salas = list(range(1,7))

def dato_aleatorio():
  return "{}-{}-{}".format(
  random.choice(pelis),
  random.choice(años),
  random.choice(salas)
  )

datos = [ dato_aleatorio() for _ in range(10000)]
with open("Peliculas.txt", "w") as f:
  for dato in datos: print(dato, file=f)
```

Answer (score 0):

Para ordenar los archivos de otra manera, pulse el botón de ver opciones en la barra de herramientas y elija Por nombre, Por tamaño, Por tipo, Por fecha de modificación o Por fecha de acceso. Por ejemplo, si selecciona Por nombre, los archivos se ordenarán según sus nombres, en orden alfabético.

Comment: Hola Alejandra, bienvenida, creo que te estás apresurando a contestar, deberías leer detenidamente loque se pide, antes de hacerlo, te recomiendo que elimines tu respuesta, para evitar recibir votos negativos.